# what does the $mode save when using stat in perl

Tags: perl

Guys im trying to see the permission of a certain file in perl using stat.

So when i did this

```
foreach (@original_files) {
    my($dev, $ino, $mode, $nlink, $uid, $gid, $rdev,
      $size, $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks) = stat ($_);

    print "$mode \n";
}
```

this outputs:

```
33204 which corresponds to the permission -rw-rw-r--
```

which i cant understand why is it 33204. <-- **This is my first question**

Next is i tried converting the $mode to octal which i know is the number system for umask.

this is my code:

```
printf ("%0\n",$mode);
```

now this outputs 100664 which i quite undersand the last 3 digits (rw-rw-r--) but i dont understand where did the first 3 digits come from ( the 100 in the 100664)
**That is my second question**

Lastly is i tried this code again:

```
printf ("%o\n", $mode & 775); #im not sure about the 775, or is it 577
```

That last code is what i desired. It outputs 664. And my question is why when i AND the $mode to i forgot the value (775 or something) it outputs the right permission.?

And OT question too: **What is the difference of $_ and @_**?

Comment: This page: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html  answers your questions.  perldoc is a great resource.

Comment: i have read that it doesnt explain my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my web host's `man 2 stat` about mode:

```
S_IFMT     0170000   bit mask for the file type bit fields
S_IFSOCK   0140000   socket
S_IFLNK    0120000   symbolic link
S_IFREG    0100000   regular file
S_IFBLK    0060000   block device
S_IFDIR    0040000   directory
S_IFCHR    0020000   character device
S_IFIFO    0010000   FIFO
S_ISUID    0004000   set UID bit
S_ISGID    0002000   set-group-ID bit (see below)
S_ISVTX    0001000   sticky bit (see below)
S_IRWXU    00700     mask for file owner permissions
S_IRUSR    00400     owner has read permission
S_IWUSR    00200     owner has write permission
S_IXUSR    00100     owner has execute permission
S_IRWXG    00070     mask for group permissions
S_IRGRP    00040     group has read permission
S_IWGRP    00020     group has write permission
S_IXGRP    00010     group has execute permission
S_IRWXO    00007     mask for permissions for others (not in group)
S_IROTH    00004     others have read permission
S_IWOTH    00002     others have write permission
S_IXOTH    00001     others have execute permission
```

(Note that the leading `0` means those numbers are octal numbers.)

You can see seven fields in the `mode` word.

```
S_IFMT   file type
S_ISUID  set UID bit
S_ISGID  set-group-ID bit
S_ISVTX  sticky bit
S_IRWXU  owner permissions
S_IRWXG  group permissions
S_IRWXO  other permissions
```

If you view the mode as its fields instead of as a number (0x81B4 = 33204 = 0100664 = 0b1000000110110100), you get:

```
S_IFMT:  S_IFREG (regular file)
S_ISUID: 0 (no set UID bit)
S_ISGID: 0 (no set-group-ID bit)
S_ISVTX: 0 (no sticky bit)
S_IRWXU: S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR (user has rw)
S_IRWXG: S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP (group has rw)
S_IRWXO: S_IROTH (other has r)
```

Doing `& 0777` is the same as doing as `& (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)` which extracts the fields containing the various permission.

---

`$_` is a variable that refers to `$main::_`. It's set by some constructs (foreach loop, `map`, `grep`) and used as the default by many operators (e.g. `say;` means `say $_;`).

The elements of `@_` are aliased to the parameters passed to the sub being executed. e.g. `$_[0]` and thus `$x` contains `4` in `sub f { my ($x) = @_; ... } f(4);`

Comment: you didnt explain why is it 33204

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated Yes, he did.  decimal 33204 = octal 100664 = S_IFREG | 0 | 0 | 0 | (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR) | (S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP) | S_IROTH.

Comment: why is it when i try this it doesnt work my $m = oct($mode); or even $m = oct ($mode & 0777)

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated, that doesn't do what you want because `oct(33204)` returns the decimal equivalent of the octal string (here, 33204) provided.  Use `sprintf "%o", 33204` to convert that to octal.

Comment: @JulianFondren yes, i found that out. lol. But sprintf only prints it. i want to compare the octal value so that i can print the exact words - writable or executable or readable if it corresponds to some octal value

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated , `printf` prints it.  `sprintf` returns a string.  But if you want to test it for user-readability, etc., just AND it with the appropriate octal mask: `$mode & 0600`.  You can even use those horrid symbolic names if you want, as the POSIX module defines them.

Answer (score 2):

1. `-rw-rw-r--` corresponds to the binary numeral `110110100` (the first - isn't a permission).  As we're dealing with groups of three bits, we use octal (which maps groups of three bits to 0-7) for convenience: 644.
2. To understand the 100 of 100644, `man 2 stat`.
3. Regarding:

   printf ("%o\n", $mode & 775); #im not sure about the 775, or is it 577

775 is decimal, not octal.  If you want only the last nine bits, then AND the number with octal 777 (= all bits set, binary 111_111_111).

```
printf "%o\n", 0100664 & 0777;  # 664
```